# Webpack custom resolve plugin: callback doesn't receive required path

Tags: webpack

I've implemented custom resolver according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29859165/2740498). I've got `entry.js` file which requires `zuka/core` module like this:

```
require('zuka/core');

document.write("It works.");
```

I have the following webpack.config.js file:

```
const MyConventionResolver = require('./MyConventionResolver');
const webpack = require('webpack');


module.exports = {
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ResolverPlugin([
            new MyConventionResolver()
        ])
    ]
};
```

The problem is that I don't get `request.path` that contains `zuka/core` inside `resolver.plugin('module', function(request, callback) {` function, however I do get other paths, so my plugin is working. Why don't I get `zuka/core`? Webpack also emits error that `zuka/core` is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be checking `request.path`, instead check for `request.request`. Each plugin receives the request object with the following properties:

> path: path to a file where a require call is processed
>
> request: module name (what's inside require)

For example, you have the following structure:

```
workdir
|
|-another
        |
        |-entry.js
```

And inside entry.js you have the following:

```
require("zuka/core");
```

So with this configuration you'll have `request.path` equal to `workdir/another` and `request.request` equal to `zuka/core`.