# Write custom webpack resolver

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, resolver

I'm planning on using a set of a little bit more sophisticated conventions to import assets in my webpack project. So I'm trying to write a plugin that should rewrite parts of requested module locators and then pass that down the resolver [waterfall](https://webpack.js.org/development/how-to-write-a-plugin/#different-plugin-shapes).

---

Let's assume we just want to

- check if a requested module starts with the `#` character and
- if so, replace that with `./lib/`. The new module locator should now be looked up by the default resolver.

This means when a file `/var/www/source.js` does `require("#example")`, it should then actually get `/var/www/lib/example.js`.

---

So far I've figured out I'm apparently supposed to use [the `module` event hook](https://webpack.js.org/api/plugins/resolver/#module-request-request-async-waterfall) for this purpose. That's also the way chosen [by other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29859165/2048874) which unfortunately did not help me too much.

So this is my take on the custom resolve plugin, it's pretty straightforward:

```
function MyResolver () {}
MyResolver.prototype.apply = function (compiler) {

  compiler.plugin('module', function (init, callback) {
    // Check if rewrite is necessary
    if (init.request.startsWith('#')) {

      // Create a new payload
      const modified = Object.assign({}, init, {
        request: './lib/' + init.request.slice(1)
      })

      // Continue the waterfall with modified payload
      callback(null, modified)
    } else {

      // Continue the waterfall with original payload
      callback(null, init)
    }
  })

}
```

However, using this (in `resolve.plugins`) doesn't work. Running webpack, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in .
Module build failed: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
 @ ./source.js 1:0-30
```

Apparently, this is not the way to do things. But since I couldn't find much example material out there on the matter, I'm a little bit out of ideas.

---

To make this easier to reproduce, I've put this exact configuration into a GitHub repo. So if you're interested in helping, you may just fetch it:

```
git clone https://github.com/Loilo/webpack-custom-resolver.git
```

Then just run `npm install` and `npm run webpack` to see the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Update:** Note that the plugin architecture changed significantly in webpack 4. The code below will no longer work on current webpack versions.
>
> If you're interested in a webpack 4 compliant version, leave a comment and I'll add it to this answer.

I've found the solution, it was mainly triggered by reading the small `doResolve()` line [in the docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/plugins/resolver).

The solution was a multiple-step process:

**1. Running `callback()` is not sufficient to continue the waterfall.**

To pass the resolving task back to webpack, I needed to replace

```
callback(null, modified)
```

with

```
this.doResolve(
  'resolve',
  modified,
  `Looking up ${modified.request}`,
  callback
)
```

**(2. Fix the webpack documentation)**

The docs were missing the third parameter (`message`) of the `doResolve()` method, resulting in an error when using the code as shown there. That's why I had given up on the `doResolve()` method when I found it before putting the question up on SO.

I've made a pull request, the docs should be fixed shortly.

**3. Don't use `Object.assign()`**

It seems that the original request object (named `init` in the question) must not be duplicated via `Object.assign()` to be passed on to the resolver.

Apparently it contains internal information that trick the resolver into looking up the wrong paths.

So this line

```
const modified = Object.assign({}, init, {
  request: './lib/' + init.request.slice(1)
})
```

needs to be replaced by this:

```
const modified = {
  path: init.path,
  request: './lib/' + init.request.slice(1),
  query: init.query,
  directory: init.directory
}
```

---

That's it. To see it a bit clearer, here's the whole `MyResolver` plugin from above now working with the mentioned modifications:

```
function MyResolver () {}
MyResolver.prototype.apply = function (compiler) {

  compiler.plugin('module', function (init, callback) {
    // Check if rewrite is necessary
    if (init.request.startsWith('#')) {

      // Create a new payload
      const modified = {
        path: init.path,
        request: './lib/' + init.request.slice(1),
        query: init.query,
        directory: init.directory
      }

      // Continue the waterfall with modified payload
      this.doResolve(
        // "resolve" just re-runs the whole resolving of this module,
        // but this time with our modified request.
        'resolve',
        modified,
        `Looking up ${modified.request}`,
        callback
      )
    } else {
      this.doResolve(
        // Using "resolve" here would cause an infinite recursion,
        // use an array of the possibilities instead.
        [ 'module', 'file', 'directory' ],
        modified,
        `Looking up ${init.request}`,
        callback
      )
    }
  })

}
```

Comment: This seems to process only files that do not have relative paths. As soon as I remove the # char the path is interpreted as relative and the resolver is bypassed. Is there any way to intercept relative paths and modify them?

Comment: Sure, just hop into the `else` branch, check the `modified.path` and adjust it as needed.

Comment: Meanwhile I found [NormalModuleReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/). This one does the trick for me. I can access any path (relative or alias). Thanks for the quick answer!