# Webpack dynamic alias resolution

Tags: webpack, webpack-3

I'm looking for a way to pass in a function via the Webpack@3.12.0 config to help Webpack dynamically resolve an alias on compile-time. I have various third-party packages that import, for example, `package-a/file-b`. However, depending on which third party package is importing `package-a`, I want it to be resolved to a different version of `package-a`; although there will be a version of `package-a` in `node_modules`, the older versions won't be in `node_modules` but a different directory. Since these are third parties, I do not want to manually alter their code. The version to use in the respective package is in the path name and there is an arbitrary number of packages.

Because `package-a` is a private package, it's not on npm nor versioned via Github.

These two have helped me get closer to this but both answers seem outdated:
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/110
- [Is it possible to create custom resolver in webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026428/is-it-possible-to-create-custom-resolver-in-webpack)

Here is what I have so far:

```
config.resolve.plugins = [{
    apply(resolver) {
        resolver.plugin('module', function(request, callback) {
            if (request.request.startsWith('package-a')) {
                this.doResolve(
                    'file',
                    Object.assign({
                        ...request,
                        request: request.request.replace(/^package-a/, `${__dirname}/versions/v2.2.0`) + '.js',
                        file: true,
                        resolved: true,
                    }),
                    null,
                    callback
                );

                return;
            }
            callback();
        });
    }
}];
```

While it properly builds, the problem with this is that it is still evaluating to the `node_modules` `package-a` -- so I guess the code isn't working at all.

Comment: what happens if instead of `${__dirname}/versions/v2.2.0`  you just write 'lorem ipsum' ?  will it break the build as one would expect ?

Comment: Did the answer help you? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be related to __dirname, which may be the __dirname of the webpack.config.js file and not your library. try to console.log(__dirname) at the plugin and see if the path is correct. also, you don't need to add '.js'

this resolver plugin works for me on WebPack 4 (slightly modified, hope to have not broken anything while adapting):

```
    const path = require('path');

    var monorepoResolver = {
      apply(resolver) {
        resolver.plugin('module', function(request, callback) {
          if (request.path.startsWith('package-a') === -1)  {
              callback();
            } else 
            {
              this.doResolve(
                'resolve',
                {
                  ...request,
                  request: request.request.replace(/^package-a/, `${__dirname}/versions/v2.2.0`),
                },
                'Edev Resolver',
                callback
              );
            }
        });
      }
    };


    module.exports = (baseConfig, env, defaultConfig) => {

      defaultConfig.resolve.plugins = defaultConfig.resolve.plugins || [];
      defaultConfig.resolve.plugins.push(monorepoResolver);


      return defaultConfig
    }
```