# Webpack. Resolve several paths with import

Tags: webpack, import

I'd like webpack to search for files in several paths. For example, if i do

```
import img from './img/smth.png'
```

in file /src/components/name/index.js, webpack try to search for this file not only in /src/components/name/img/ but also in /src/common/img

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, it is not possible to change relative path resolution. Using `resolve.alias` you can change Webpack resolution for **module paths** but not for absolute or relative imports.

However, you can write a custom plugin and introduce your own module resolution algorithm. The plugin would be similar to the one implemented here:

[Is it possible to create custom resolver in Webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29859165/5723098)